# Как закодировать бинарные файлы в base64 с помощью javascript?

Tags: base64, activex, файлы, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Вот суть задачи: при анкетировании человеку отправляется пара xml + xsl, которая открывается в IE как html. В анкете могут быть указаны вопросы и файлы, которые анкетируемый должен прикрепить (по кнопке "выбрать" он указывает путь к файлу). Затем с помощью javascript **файл кодируется в строку base64 и записывается в одно из полей xml**. Заполненную анкету, с прикреплёнными к ней вложениями, анкетируемый отправляет автору анкеты.

---

Интересует момент кодирования файла методом base64.
Функцию кодирования я взял отсюда: [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript#246813), она прекрасно обрабатывает текстовые строки и текстовые файлы, но бинарные файлы, например, картинки, потом раскодировать не получается. Для того, чтобы передать этой функции файл я использую File System Object:

```
FileName = ... ;
var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
var file = fs.GetFile(FileName);
var stream = file.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0);
var content = stream.ReadAll();
stream.Close();
TextToXML = Base64.encode(content);
```

Точно не знаю, в чём проблема - в base64 или в том, как я ей подаю файл. Как раз в этом вопрос: как закодировать бинарные файлы, чтобы потом правильно раскодировать? Повторюсь, текстовые файлы кодируются правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Вы выбрали неправильный вариант решения задачи. Политики безопасности нормальных браузеров не позволяют javascript получать доступк файловой системе на компьютере пользователя, т.к. это является огромной брешью в системе безопасности.

Если вам необходимо анкетировать пользователей, сделайте вебсайт с регистрацией, в нем реализуйте анкету. Загрузку файлов на вебсервер можно организовать на любом языке для веб программирования.

UPD://
Хотя вру, если не хочется заморачиваться с вебсервером, можно попробовать [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) Позволяет создавать кроссплатформенные приложения на javascript+html+css с отображением во встроенном вебките. Довольно интересный проект :]

Comment: Почитал про node webkit. Правда, интересно.  
Что вы предлагаете: рассылать анкеты вместе с webkit и сделать bash, чтобы пользователем всё это удобно запускалось? Или пользователь как-то по-другому сможет заполнить анкету?  
Я так понял, node думает, что он работает с Chromium? То есть писать надо всё как под Chrome, а не как под IE - но зато открывать в своём webkit?

Comment: Если я так сделаю, какие компоненты я смогу там использовать? Просто большую часть кода написали до меня, и хотелось бы её использовать...   
Для чтения бинарных файлов наверно можно использовать File API, который есть в Chrome?  
Ещё у меня точно используется ActiveX (как я понимаю, он из IE) - он поддерживается или можно его на что-то заменить?  
И есть ли в node XSLT-парсер?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашёлся - надо юзать [ADODB.Stream](http://javascript.ru/forum/css-html-internet-explorer/23488-analog-funkcii-file_get_contents-dlya-lokalnojj-mashiny.html).

---

на какое-то время забросил эту тему, теперь вот пришлось к ней вернуться.

по постановке задания ADODB использовать не получается, так как это не встроенный компонент и вполне может отсутствовать у рядового пользователя... **Что делать?**

Answer (score -1):

[[@nolka](/users/8440/nolka)](/users/8440/nolka), так человек скрипты вояет же на activeX.

[[@danstaf](/users/9230/danstaf)](/users/9230/danstaf), поиск выдает достаточное кол-во результатов. Вот один из них: [ActiveX FileSystemObject - проблемы с чтением бинарного файла и отправкой](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/26839-activex-filesystemobject-problemy-s-chteniem-binarnogo-fajjla-i-otpravkojj.html).

Comment: @lampa, человек написал, что

> по постановке задания ADODB использовать не получается, так как это
> не встроенный компонент и вполне может отсутствовать у рядового 
> пользователя...

Comment: Вы правы, с ADODB у меня даже всё работает, но использовать его нельзя.  
Как я понял, изначально у пользователя ADODB скорее всего не активирован. По ссылке @lampa, __lord2kim__ предлагает сначала активировать ADODB, это наверно решит данную проблему? Но если ADODB отсутствует как компонент?